# Raspberry pi USB camera feed (LOCAL ONLY - no network)

Tags: usb, camera, hdmi, pi-1

I've come across many tutorials that allow for the network streaming of a USB camera from a pi.

I simply want to view a live stream FROM the raspberry pi ON the raspberry pi.

Setup:
Wired usb camera outside house feeds raspberry pi inside my house. 
The SAME raspberry pi then takes that stream and relays it to a wall-mounted tv (monitor) via hdmi.

Other devices do not have to view this stream.
Many of the camera server solutions seem out of my reach as ethernet cabling to this device is not an option. Also read that attempting this via Wifi would yield poor results.

Am attempting to use a raspberry Pi 1 Model B but can scale to the latest model 3 if necessary.

Is this possible or already common?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GUVCView.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install guvcview
```

This program only works with USB cameras.